# SoapException In Web Service

Tags: asp.net, web-reference, soapexception

I have a tab control. 1st tab has a grid, one of the columns is a checkbox. The user selects it and clicks "Next" under the tab, then goes to next tab.

I'm using a web reference to get the values. When the page loads for first time, the reference works and the values can be reached, the grid gets binded.

But when I click on "Next", postback happens and it tries to bind the grid again, then the reference gives "SoapExpection". Here are details:

-> I select a row then click "Next":

```
protected void gridView_HtmlRowCreated(object sender, ASPxGridViewTableRowEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.RowType == GridViewRowType.Data)
            {
                   //bla bla bla
                   //I get the error here:
                   ClassEntity tmpObjects = webService.callObjects(rowID);
                   //bla bla bla
            {
        {
```

-> And the function named callObjects(int ID) (In Reference.cs)

```
[System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapDocumentMethodAttribute("...", RequestNamespace="...", ResponseNamespace="...", Use=System.Web.Services.Description.SoapBindingUse.Literal, ParameterStyle=System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapParameterStyle.Wrapped)]
        public ClassEntity callObjects(int ID) {
            object[] results = this.Invoke("callObjects", new object[] {
                        ID});
            return ((ClassEntity)(results[0]));
```

And the exact error:
"SoapException: Server was unable to process request. Object reference not set to an instance of an object"

Any ideas, suggestions or... Solutions? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I was using username and password to reach the web reference in a class that inheritences from System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHeader.

I was defining username and password in Page_Load, but it seems it was cleaning these values after I click to "Next". So I made same declerations under gridView_HtmlRowCreated event, and it worked.

Hope that helps anybody like me.